# Open particular activity when app comes to foreground

Tags: android

When my app comes to the foreground I want to open a particular activity. It doesn't matter which activity was previously active before app goes to the background.

How can I do this?

Comment: How many activities do you have in your app?

Comment: almost 9 activities @babadaba

Answer (score 0):

Make an static function to your utility class like -

```
public static void launchForgroundActivity(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ForgroundActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

In every activity maintain a flag for going background like -

```
boolean isBackground = false;

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    isBackground = true;
}
```

Now check in onStart and if isBackground value is true then launch the forground activity.

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(isBackground)
        Utility.launchForgroundActivity(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Hope it will help :)